# Difference between indexcontroller and viewresolver in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Im newbie to Spring framework. I started learning few basic things from [this link](http://netbeans.org/kb/68/web/quickstart-webapps-spring.html). I was stuck with this topic. What is the difference b/w View and Index. Its not  much clear in tat doc

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You see that indexController extends PrameterizedViewController which is a basic controller that always returns a named view. The advantage of this controller is that the client is not exposed to the concrete view technology but only to the controller url.

ViewResolver is of type InternalViewResolver, this means it will resolve views such as jsp, servlet etc .

So you would use viewResolver to link to another jsp or servlet and the indexController would be used in order for your request to be processed by a @Controller class.